# #pragma pack() with push and pop vs unpack

Tags: c, pragma

I have this sample program below

```
#include <stdio.h>                              
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct{
  char a;
  int b;
  char c;
}st_a;
#pragma pack(pop)

typedef struct{
  char a;
  int b;
  char c;
}st_b;


int main()
{
  printf("size of struct a %zd \n",sizeof(st_a));
  printf("size of struct b %zd \n",sizeof(st_b));

  return 0;
}
```

Output of the above program is

```
size of struct a 6 
size of struct b 12
```

Now if I change the struct declaration as below:

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct{
  char a;
  int b;
  char c;
}st_a;
#pragma unpack()
```

Output of the program is

```
size of struct a 6 
size of struct b 6
```

Why is this difference in the behaviour? My understanding was that both structure declarations are doing the same thing.

I am running this on my MBP.

```
$gcc --version 

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using MSVC. AFAICT there is no pragma `unpack()`

Comment: @Hasturkun - The Renesas compilers do support `#pragma unpack` though, but don't appear to support `#pragma pack(push)` :S.

Comment: I am running this program on my MBP - 2015 :) in case it matters

Comment: In which case, Clang uses the same definition for `#pragma pack` as MSVC, so see @Hasturkun's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler knows nothing about `unpack()` pragma, and just ignores it, so the same packing rules are applied to both structures.

`MSVC` compiler will issue a warning about unknown `#pragma` directives on first warning level.

Both `GCC` and `Clang` keep silence by default. You need to use `-Wunknown-pragmas` flag.

Comment: Ignores it?  First I've heard.  Those whining compilers will complain about anything...

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, `MSVC` issues a warning by default, `GCC` requires `-Wunknown-pragmas`. I guess `Clang` also keeps silence by default. Anyway, they aren't treated as errors.